# Why is ListView not scrolling consistently?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, lag

I am currently working on a `ListView` that contains around 80 to 100 items (`TextViews`). I don't think it is too much content, but when i scroll (with fingers) the `ListView` is bobbing or laging. However, when I use the "fast-scroll-button" - that thing on the right of the `ListView` - the scrolling appears very consistent and smooth.

Did anyone have the same problem? I tested the `ListView` on my HTC Sensation.

Here is my ListView code:

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/list_view"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:scrollingCache="true">

</ListView>
```

And the Java code:

```
adptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(iF, R.layout.list_item, showing) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup grp) {

            LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
            lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Icon
            ImageView v = new ImageView(this.getContext());
            // v.setBackgroundDrawable(iF.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cube_icon));

            // Text
            TextView txt = new TextView(this.getContext());
            txt.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12")));
            txt.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            txt.setText(this.getItem(position));
            txt.setTextColor(getLineColor(position));

            // Shortcut
            LinearLayout shortLin = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
            shortLin.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            LayoutParams par = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            shortLin.setLayoutParams(par);

            TextView s = new TextView(this.getContext());
            s.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12")));
            s.setWidth(iF.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.shortcutWidth));
            s.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            s.setText(getShortcut(position));

            shortLin.addView(s);

            // Return
            txt.invalidate();
            v.invalidate();
            s.invalidate();

            lin.addView(v);
            lin.addView(txt);
            lin.addView(shortLin);

            return lin;
        }
    };
```

As you can see, I made a customized `ListView`. The `ArrayAdapter` will be added in a different method (not shown here).

Thanks in advance

Adrian

Comment: not sure if you have to invalidate your textviews all the time in your getView()

Comment: yes. this is probably not nessesary. I don't really know what it does. found this in some google research :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you remember about cache?

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_view_home_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);

        holder.title.setText("blah");
        view.setTag(holder);            
    } else {        
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    return view;
```

and

```
    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
}
```

?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I never heard about LayoutInflater. I will go to android dev page and read more about that.

Comment: To add to this answer, a great screencast of a Google IO event on ListView's would be a good thing to watch.  It helped me out   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Remember about checking good answer on this site ! ;-)
I got the same problem yesterday

Comment: Ok. I studied the hole thing about Inflater! Now, last question: Where do I do my setTextSize()? I have to update it so i cant make it in xml because the user can change it in preferences.

Comment: Use it like setting text ( holder.title.setText("blah") ), but remember about cachcing (when you dont save it propertly, you will lose it afrer swipe)

So it will be holder.s.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12"))); or so

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. When I scroll down, everything before is deleted. When I go up again it's placing something else.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating every `View` element for your list dynamically every time you pull a view. That's possibly the most inefficient mechanism ever :).

As a first step, see if you can layout your view in XML. Makes things easier to manage.

Even if you don't do that, use the `convertView` parameter. Its sole reason for existence is to keep you from having to reallocate views if possible. If `convertView` is non-null, it has all the views you created in a previous invocation of `getView()`. All you have to do is fill in the appropriate information in each view (essentially, in your case, the `setText()` calls). If `convertView` is null, create your views.

Also, don't `invalidate()`. At a minimum, without the XML layout, here's a rewritten version that should be a bit faster.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup grp) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
        lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // Icon
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this.getContext());
        // v.setBackgroundDrawable(iF.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cube_icon));

        // Text
        TextView txt = new TextView(this.getContext());
        txt.setId(1);
        txt.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12")));
        txt.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        txt.setTextColor(getLineColor(position));

        // Shortcut
        LinearLayout shortLin = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
        shortLin.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        LayoutParams par = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        shortLin.setLayoutParams(par);

        TextView s = new TextView(this.getContext());
        s.setId(2);
        s.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12")));
        s.setWidth(iF.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.shortcutWidth));
        s.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        shortLin.addView(s);
        lin.addView(v);
        lin.addView(txt);
        lin.addView(shortLin);
    }

    TextView txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(1);
    txt.setText(this.getItem(position));
    TextView txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(2);
    txt.setText(getShortcut(position));


    return lin;
}
```

Again, not the best way or a best practice, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this code as soon as I can. But in this code, there is no inflating such as Damian recommended. However, thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with this solution:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (view == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) iF.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
                holder.shortcut = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_short);

                holder.title.setId(1);
                holder.shortcut.setId(2);

                holder.title.setText(getItem((position)));
                holder.shortcut.setText(getShortcut(position));

                holder.title.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("pref_txtSize", "12")));
                holder.shortcut.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(prefs.getString("prefs_txtSize", "12")));

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(1);
                title.setText(getItem(position));

                TextView shortcut = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(2);
                shortcut.setText(getShortcut(position));
            }

            return view;
        }
```

I am really happy right now that it worked. It is 00:33, so I think I go to bed now. Enough work for today (yesterday :)

Thanks for all the support